# How to copy stream to many streams async C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, stream

I have TCP server , what recieve big data without a break.
And I need to broadcast this stream to many clients.

**UPDATE:**
I need to broadcast video stream. Perhaps there are ready solutions?

Comment: Please provide more detail about the code you've tried and what has/has not worked.

Comment: is it necessary to use TCP for broadcasting ? your requirement is usually implement via UDP...

Comment: The data what I tried to broadcast - it is stream.

Comment: TCP isn't necessary, if I can connect to UPD from silverlight application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this asynchronously, then you can take advantage of the [`System.Threading.Tasks` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx).

First, you'll need a map of the [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) instances to the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) that can be waited on for completion:

```
IDictionary<Stream, Task> streamToTaskMap = outputStreams.
    ToDictionary(s => s, Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });
```

There's a slight overhead in the above, in that there's a wasted `Task` instance that does nothing, but that price is small given the number of `Task` instances and continuations you need to perform.

From there, you would read the content from the stream and then write it out to each of the `Stream` instances asynchronously:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[<buffer size>];
int read = 0;

while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    // The buffer to copy into.
    byte[] copy = new byte[read];

    // Perform the copy.
    Array.Copy(buffer, copy, read);

    // Cycle through the map, and replace the task with a continuation
    // on the task.
    foreach (Stream stream in streamToTaskMap.Keys)
    {
        // Continue.
        streaToTaskMap[stream] = streaToTaskMap[stream].ContinueWith(t => {
            // Write the bytes from the copy.
            stream.Write(copy, 0, copy.Length);
        });
    }
}
```

And in the end, you can wait on all of the streams written to by calling:

```
Task.WaitAll(streamToTaskMap.Values.ToArray());
```

There are a few things to note.

First, the copy of `buffer` is needed because of the lambda that is passed to [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx); the lambda is a closure that would encapsulate `buffer` and because it is processing asynchronously, the contents are likely to change.  Each continuance needs its own copy of the buffer to read.

This is also why the call to [`Stream.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx) uses the [`Array.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) property; otherwise, the `read` variable would have to be copied through each iteration of the loop.

Additionally, it would be more ideal to be able to utilize the [`BeginWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginwrite.aspx)/[`EndWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.endwrite.aspx) methods on the `Stream` class; because there is no `ContinueWithAsync` method which will take a `Task` and continue with an asynchronous method, there is no benefit to calling the async versions of read.

This is one of those cases where it might be better to call BeginWrite/EndWrite yourself (as well as [`BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx)/[`EndRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.endread.aspx)) in order to make the most of async operations; of course, this will be a bit more complex because you won't have the encapsulation of the operation's result that `Task` provides, and you will have to take the same precautions with the `buffer` if you use anonymous methods/closures.

Answer (score 1):

Spawn off a thread passing the stream to it, as well as the streams to write to

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int btsRead = 0;

while ((btsRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    foreach (Stream oStream in outputStreams)
        oStream.Write(buffer, 0, btsRead);
}
```

EDIT: To parallelize the writes:

replace the foreach chunk with:

```
Parallel.ForEach(outputStreams, oStream =>
{
    oStream.Write(buffer, 0, btsRead);
});
```

Comment: "foreach"? Is it good solution? And what if I wiil have about 1000 clients?

Comment: foreach is the same as a for loop. The code I just presented should be run in a background thread spawned by the server when it receives the upload stream. You could try other techniques such as do asynchronous writes to the client stream to further amortize the cost, but what I presented is a relatively simple solution that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are wanting to thread your application.  Here's a simple example of threading and TCP/IP

[C# Tutorial - Simple Threaded TCP Server | Switch on the Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)